# How to query for elasticsearch entry's TTL?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following:

```
final settings = (ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
        .put('index._ttl.enabled', true)
        .put('index.gateway.type', 'none')
        .put('index.number_of_shards', 1)
        .put('index.number_of_replicas', 0)
        .put('index.store.type', 'memory')
        .put('node.http.enabled', false)
        .build())
node = (org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
        .clusterName(clusterName)
        .local(true)
        .settings(settings)
        .node())
final Client client = node.client()

client.prepareIndex('index', 'type')
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                .field('_ttl', '111111')
                .field('field', 'value')
                .endObject())
        .setRefresh(true)
        .execute()
        .actionGet()
```

The following:

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch('builds')
        .setQuery(boolQuery()
                .must(termQuery('_type', 'test')))
        .execute()
        .actionGet()
```

returns `searchResponse.internalResponse.hits.hits[0].source` as:

```
[0] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@7024}"_ttl" -> "111111"
[1] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@7027}"field" -> "value"
```

But the following returns `0L`:

```
client.prepareCount('index')
        .setQuery(boolQuery()
                .must(fieldQuery('_ttl', '111111'))
                .must(termQuery('_type', 'type'))
                .must(fieldQuery('field', 'value')))
        .execute()
        .actionGet()
        .count
```

How do I go about ensuring the TTL is being set?

Comment: What does you mapping look like? Did you enable the [_ttl field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html)?

Comment: I _think_ it's enabled with `.put('index._ttl.enabled', true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, and it's not documented, but try adding this to the settings builder:

```
.put('index._ttl.index', 'not_analyzed')
```

You may want to consider setting `index._ttl.store` to `true` as well, depending on how you're querying.

It seems a bit redundant to index that field explicitly, though.  It's probably already indexed somewhere, even if you don't have direct access to it.